# Question over Lagrange's Theorem and the number of cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the subgroup $H = \{0, 3\}$ of $Z_6 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

By Lagrange's Theorem, there needs to be $6/2=3$ cosets. Lets focus on left cosets.

But can't there be $5$?

$0+H$

$1+H$

$2+H$

$4+H$

$5+H$

My question is why are the last $2$ omitted? How do you decide which 'numbers' to pick from $Z_6$?

Comment: Why can't there be $6$? You omitted $3+H$ after all. Hey, while we're at it, we could create an infinite number of cosets, like $-1+H$ and $100+H$ etc. Why aren't there an infinite number of cosets? Try to write out the elements of the first three cosets. Any elements left of $Z_6$ not accounted for?

Comment: Ah thank you. Recheck my math. I was multiplying $4*0$ instead of adding. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in $\mathbb Z_6$ .So for $x+H=\{x+0,x+3\}=\{x,x+3\}$ both $x$ and $x+3$ will be actually in modulo 6.Now just list all the left cosets:

$0+H=\{0,3\}$

$1+H=\{1,4\}$

$2+H=\{2,5\}$

$3+H=\{3,6\}$

As we are in $\mathbb Z_6$,$3+H=\{3,6\}=\{3,0\}=0+H$

So for the same reason we have

$4+H=\{4,7\}=\{4,1\}=1+H$ and

$5+H=\{5,8\}=\{5,2\}=2+H$

Thus there are 3 left cosets.